# How to i transform a very large dataframe to get the count of values in all columns (without using df.stack or df.apply)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a very large dataframe (~3 million rows) and i need the count of values from multiple columns, grouped by time related data.

I have tried to stack the columns but the resulting dataframe was very long and wouldn't fit in the memory. Similarly df.apply gave memory issues.

For example if my sample dataframe is like,

```
id,date,field1,field2,field3
1,1/1/2014,abc,,abc
2,1/1/2014,abc,,abc
3,1/2/2014,,abc,abc
4,1/4/2014,xyz,abc,
1,1/1/2014,,abc,abc
1,1/1/2014,xyz,qwe,xyz
4,1/7/2014,,qwe,abc
2,1/4/2014,qwe,,qwe
2,1/4/2014,qwe,abc,qwe
2,1/5/2014,abc,,abc
3,1/5/2014,xyz,xyz,
```

I have written the following script that does the needed for a small sample but fails in a large dataframe.

```py
df.set_index(["id", "date"], inplace=True)
df = df.stack(level=[0])
df = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).value_counts()
df = df.unstack(level=[1,2])
```

I also have a solution via `apply` but it has the same complications.

The expected result is,

```
date 1/1/2014           1/4/2014 ...  1/5/2014 1/4/2014 1/7/2014     
          abc  xyz  qwe      qwe ...       xyz      xyz      abc  qwe
id                               ...                                 
1         4.0  2.0  1.0      NaN ...       NaN      NaN      NaN  NaN
2         2.0  NaN  NaN      4.0 ...       NaN      NaN      NaN  NaN
3         NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN ...       2.0      NaN      NaN  NaN
4         NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN ...       NaN      1.0      1.0  1.0
```

I am looking for a more optimized version of what I have written.

Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Do you really need it unstacked to such a level and so sparse - could you work with  something like: `df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'date']).groupby(['id', 'date', 'value']).size()`...? (perhaps with an extra `.unstack()` at the end if you really want those as columns)

Comment: Though I assume if `stack` fails `melt` will only be more likely to fail, since it will have more rows (it doesn't drop `NaN`)

Comment: Also, what is the `apply` that gave you an issue?

Comment: I grouped the df by date and member and then applied apply but it code ran for hours without an output.

Comment: @JonClements the melt method works similar to stack so expanding the df row wise wont help, I think the dataframe has to be expanded on its width.

Comment: @shreyansh well - making it longer than wide means you've not got so many multi-level columns with sparse data, so it should be smaller... it's worth a go. Your current approach, on your sample data, a single row is about the size of the entire DF with the melt/groupby

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `stack`. Therefore, another solution is using `crosstab` on `id` with each `date` and `fields` columns. Finally, `concat` them together, `groupby()` the index and `sum`. Use listcomp on `df.columns[2:]` to create each `crosstab` (note: I assume the first 2 columns is `id` and `date` as your sample):

```
pd.concat([pd.crosstab([df.id], [df.date, df[col]]) for col in df.columns[2:]]).groupby(level=0).sum()

Out[497]:
   1/1/2014           1/2/2014 1/4/2014           1/5/2014      1/7/2014
        abc  qwe  xyz      abc      abc  qwe  xyz      abc  xyz      abc  qwe
id
1         4  1.0  2.0      0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0
2         2  0.0  0.0      0.0      1.0  4.0  0.0      2.0  0.0      0.0  0.0
3         0  0.0  0.0      2.0      0.0  0.0  0.0      0.0  2.0      0.0  0.0
4         0  0.0  0.0      0.0      1.0  0.0  1.0      0.0  0.0      1.0  1.0
```

I think showing `0` is better than `NaN`. However, if you want `NaN` instead of `0`, you just need to chain additional `replace` as follows:

```
pd.concat([pd.crosstab([df.id], [df.date, df[col]]) for col in df.columns[2:]]).groupby(level=0).sum().replace({0: np.nan})

Out[501]:
   1/1/2014           1/2/2014 1/4/2014           1/5/2014      1/7/2014
        abc  qwe  xyz      abc      abc  qwe  xyz      abc  xyz      abc  qwe
id
1       4.0  1.0  2.0      NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN  NaN      NaN  NaN
2       2.0  NaN  NaN      NaN      1.0  4.0  NaN      2.0  NaN      NaN  NaN
3       NaN  NaN  NaN      2.0      NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN  2.0      NaN  NaN
4       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN      1.0  NaN  1.0      NaN  NaN      1.0  1.0
```